# Using rollup plugin for commonjs, but still get 'require is not defined' when loading module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, svelte, rollup

I am using rollup and Svelte for an app using the Twilio Video SDK. I have the rollup plugins for `resolve` and `commonjs` loaded.

I am loading the SDK with rollup, and running:

```
import Video from "twilio-video";
```

However after running `npm run build` (with no errors), at runtime I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This error occurs in `node_modules/twilio-video/es5/util/insightspublisher/index.js` - ie, `twilio-video` itself is using `require()`

**How can I fix this?**

I've tried the `dynamicRequireTargets` option [per the documentation](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#dynamicrequiretargets):

```
  commonjs({
    dynamicRequireTargets: [
      // include using a glob pattern (either a string or an array of strings)
      'node_modules/twilio-video/*.js',
    ]
  }),
```

But still get the same error.

Full `rollup.config.js` is below.

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;
    
    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        nodePolyfills(),
        json(),
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('bundle.css');
            },
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
        }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({ sourceMap: !production }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Comment: Does not sound like an issue for dynamicRequiteTargets to me. `require` will be ignored if the module is identified as ESM because it also contains imports or exports. Could this be the case? Then you should do two things: Tell them that they should fix their module format and try the transformMixedEsModules option for the time being.

Comment: Also, try moving the commonjs plugin to the top in your config. Maybe another plugin is messing up the module format before it is passed to the commonjs plugin. If that works, it would be the preferred option.